# uploading file to AWS S3 PHP SDK without Access Key based on evironment

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

How to upload files to S3 using php sdk without access key based on environment( Sandbox or Live )

Comment: How will do without access key? You need one atleast!

Comment: based on bucket name and if environment is in live mode it have to upload file without access key and if its sandbox mode it have to use access key